# for each table push to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm a beginner with code, 
I'm trying to run on this table and get the text from each `.winner` class and push it to an Array,
 so instead of getting:
["aa","aa","dd"]
I'm getting
["aaaadd","aaaadd","aaaadd"]

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var arr = [];
    var winner = $('.winner').text() ;

     for ( i = 0; i < $('table').length ; i++ ) {           
        arr.push(winner);
     }

     console.log(arr);      

});
```

HTML:

```
    <table>      
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td class="winner">aa</td>
            <td>bb</td>
            <td>cc</td>
            <td>dd</td>
        </tr>
   </table>

   <table>      
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td class="winner">aa</td>
            <td>bb</td>
            <td>cc</td>
            <td>dd</td>
        </tr>
   </table>

   <table>      
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td class="winner">dd</td>
            <td>cc</td>
            <td>bb</td>
            <td>aa</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

I guess something is wrong with my for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [];

$('table .winner').each(function () {
   arr.push($(this).text());  
})
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/jivedi/1/edit?html,js,output)

or version without class `.winner`

```
$('table').each(function () {
   arr.push($(this).find('tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(1).text());
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/jivedi/2/edit?html,js,output)

`$('table .winner')` - returns 3 `td's` with class `.winner`

`$(this).text()` - get text from current element.

In your example `$('.winner').text()` returns text "aaaadd", then you get `$('table').length` (will be 3) and three times push the same text to `arr`

Answer (score 0):

The sentence

```
var winner = $('.winner')
```

will give you an array of objects, so you need to loop each of them and call text() method for each one.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
var winner = $('.winner').text();
```

You are getting a combined texts from all the `td` elements marked as `winner` (see docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/)).

Then, for each `table`, to push this value to the array:

```
 for ( i = 0; i < $('table').length ; i++ ) {           
    arr.push(winner);
 }
```

This is actually not necessary.
What you want is probably:

```
var winners = $('.winner');

for (var i = 0; i < winners.length(); ++i) {
    arr.push(winners.eq(i).text());
}
```